# How do I print Google Calendar to show full range of hours?

Tags: google-calendar

When I try to print my weekly Google Calendar, it shows roughly 6 am - 3 pm.  I need it to print at least through 5 pm and maybe longer.  Any suggestions on how to adjust the range that prints?

Answer (score 3):

Google uses some sort of auto logic to determine the display time window. This is not customization directly in Google Calendar. Here are two work-arounds/alternatives:

1. Put in a 'dummy' appointment(s) to dictate the printable time line. Example: If you want 8am to 6pm, put a dummy apt at 8am and one ending at 6pm to get Google to print this time window.
2. Use an App.  If on Windows an app called wincalendar converts Google Calendar to Microsoft Word/Excel format. Unlike Google Calendar, it supports a user-selected start/end time window.

Answer (score 3):

Go to labs under the setting menu to the far right and activate the hide/show mornings and nights. Then define the day. If you drag the bar to 6 a.m., 12-6 a.m. will consolidate, and if you drag the end-of-the-day bar to 6 p.m., 6-12 will consolidate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Mac, you can sync your Google Calendar with iCal and print from there. It keeps everything on one page! I haven't used a Windows computer in a while, but I believe that Outlook Calendar can do it too...

Answer (score 0):

Take a screen shot of the hours/events you want to see and paste into Word, then print.  Not elegant but it works.